# (CSS) Set Id for Class How to Use

Tags: css, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid and i want to set white color to th's font.

When i set this css code to Layout it effects all grids. But all i want is to set white color to grids which has id like #grid id no all of them.

```
.k-grid-header th.k-header>.k-link {
    display: block;
    min-height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: -0.5em -0.6em -0.4em -0.6em;
    padding: .5em .6em .4em .6em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    **color: white;**
}
```

How can i set class for spesific id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML you have st. like `<div id="yourid" class="k-grid-header">` and in CSS:

```
#yourid.k-grid-header th.k-header > .k-link {...}
```

Or, if ID is on parent of `.k-grid-header`:

```
<div id="yourid">
    <div class="k-grid-header">
        ...

<style>
     #yourid .k-grid-header th.k-header > .k-link {...}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
#id .yourclass {
color:#fff;
}
```

OR, if CLASS is on parent of ID

```
.yourclass #id  {
color:#fff;
}
```